# Is it possible to initialize a subclass with some base class parameters, without explicitly passing them as parameters in the base class constructor?

Tags: python

There might be no practical reason to do this, especially if a base class is abstract, but I'm curious to find out if it is possible....

Is there a way to initialize a subclass with *some* of the base class parameters, without ever explicitly passing them as parameters in the base class constructor?

For example, Employee is the base class and will use sets and gets (nothing is passed when initialized) ....

```
class Employee(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.EmployeeID = ""
    self.Name = ""
    self.Address = ""
    self.DateOfBirth = ""
```

But what if we wanted to pass in EmployeeID and Name as parameters when initializing it from the subclass?

```
class SalaryEmployee(Employee):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(??)
    self.MonthlyPayment = 0
    self.HoursThisMonth = 0
    self.PublicHoliday = True
    self.Pension = True

SallyonSalary = SalaryEmployee("AB123", "Sally")
```

Is this possible, technically?

Comment: Since the parent class doesn't accept any parameters, you can't pass anything to `super().__init__()` here. If you made `Employee.__init__` accept parameters, that'd be a different story.

Comment: FWIW, those empty getters and setters are superfluous and unpythonic. If they don't do any validation or additional logic, omit them and just assign `EmployeeID` directly. If you *do* need to add logic later, you can switch them to a `@property` without needing to change anything else.

Comment: Thank you both. @deceze, that's what I suspected... there's no practical reason, but I was just curious if it was possible within the language

Comment: If you want to just pass remaining args to a subfunction, you can just use `*args` and `*kwargs`.